# xml output in curl php

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am reading data from an api with curl library in php. when i call that api in POSTMAN tool.output comes out to be in xml which i require.but when i call that url with headers with curl library,i get the output in browser which is not in xml format.but i want it to be in xml format.

Please check the code below and help in correcting please.

```
    <?php
    header('Content-type: application/xml');
    function httpGet($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();  

        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    //  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'header1: value1',
        'header2:value2'
        ));

        $output=curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
        return $output;
    }

    $data= httpGet("https://somehost/api/id.xml");
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
    echo $xml->asXML();
    ?>
```

Comment: you have a issue with your syntax 
   value1','header2:value2')); (at this point your your quote mark is open and making the rest of the scrip invalid)

Comment: i added the quote their in header